# Is OpenSearch deprecated on Chrome / IE ? Alternatives?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, opensearch

Our website used to have OpenSearch implemented and well supported by Firefox, Chrome and IE. It appears now that only Firefox still supports it. What about the other browsers, have they deprecated it?

Checking the original page of the spec on http://www.opensearch.org/Documentation/Frequently_asked_questions and the Wikipedia page about it, we have found no news about its support.

For reference, the original code and explanation on our help section is here: http://colnect.com/en/help/collecting/opensearch

Thanks